# Performing a simple HTTP GET with Dispatch

Tags: scala, http, scala-dispatch

The following is a valid query in a browser (e.g. Firefox):

```
http://www.freesound.org/api/sounds/search/?q=barking&api_key=074c0b328aea46adb3ee76f6918f8fae
```

yielding a JSON document:

```
{
    "num_results": 610, 
    "sounds": [
        {
            "analysis_stats": "http://www.freesound.org/api/sounds/115536/analysis/", 
            "analysis_frames": "http://www.freesound.org/data/analysis/115/115536_1956076_frames.json", 
            "preview-hq-mp3": "http://www.freesound.org/data/previews/115/115536_1956076-hq.mp3", 
            "original_filename": "Two Barks.wav", 
            "tags": [
                "animal", 
                "bark", 
                "barking", 
                "dog", 
                "effects", 
 ...
```

I am trying to perform this query with [Dispatch 0.9.4](http://dispatch.databinder.net/Dispatch.html). Here's a `build.sbt`:

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.0"

libraryDependencies += "net.databinder.dispatch" %% "dispatch-core" % "0.9.4"
```

From `sbt console`, I do the following:

```
import dispatch._
val q = url("http://www.freesound.org/api/sounds/search")
   .addQueryParameter("q", "barking")
   .addQueryParameter("api_key", "074c0b328aea46adb3ee76f6918f8fae")
val res = Http(q OK as.String)
```

But the promise always completes with the following error:

```
res0: dispatch.Promise[String] = Promise(!Unexpected response status: 301!)
```

So what am I doing wrong? [Here is the API documentation](http://freesound.org/docs/api/resources.html) in case it helps.

Comment: What does `q OK as.String` print?  (Also, you do know that 301 is the "moved permanently" code, right?)

Comment: @rex `(http://www.freesound.org/api/sounds/search  GET,dispatch.OkFunctionHandler@7fc4fe21)`. I have no good knowledge of HTTP, but it works perfectly if I put the url in the browser.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can enable redirect following with the `configure` method on the `Http` executor:

```
Http.configure(_ setFollowRedirects true)(q OK as.String)
```

You could also pull the `Location` out of the `301` response manually, but that's going to be a lot less convenient.

Comment: Great, thanks Rex and Travis; I have no clue how this redirection works etc., but this solution works!

Comment: A server X gives me a redirection (status code 302) and also sends me several cookies. This line of code works great : I am redirected and I send the right cookies. Nevertheless, I lose the information of the cookies that were sent with the redirection : is there a way to get them (except by handling manually the redirection?)